# jquery.rotate error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have an image that I am trying to rotate 30 degrees and move horizontally across a page. However, I don't think I am handling the jquery right because I am getting several errors in the Firefox Web Console. Here are the errors:

```
[10:30:27.260] ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined @ file:///home/ladmin/Desktop/javascriptAnimations/jquery.rotate.1-1.js:1
[10:30:27.274] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ file:///home/ladmin/Desktop/javascriptAnimations/si110cockroach.html
[10:31:03.416] ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ file:///home/ladmin/Desktop/javascriptAnimations/si110cockroach.html:12
```

I included the script tags with the jquery source at the top like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.rotate.1-1.js"></script>
```

And here is the code where I call the jquery:

```
function moveLeft(object,x,y){
        $(object).rotateRight(30);
        object.style.right = x + "px";
        object.style.top   = y + "px";

        if (x < 0 || x > 1500 || y < 0 || y > 1500)
        {
            object.style.visibility="hidden";
        }
        else
        {               
            var t = setTimeout(function() { moveLeft(object,x+3,y+0); }, 5);
        }
    }
```

Am I not including the source file right or am I not calling the jquery right?

Comment: Guessing you are not including jQuery or it is in the wrong order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include [jquery.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js) before the `jquery.rotate.1-1.js` script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.rotate.1-1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do I need to download `jquery.min.js` and put it in that directory as well?

Comment: Yes you need to have jQuery, wither download it or link to a [CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide).

Comment: @ridecontrol53 Yeap, `jquery.rotate.1-1.js` plugin should work ,only and only if core `jQuery` library is included.